# Formatting results from Powershell Select statement for ManagedBy Attribute in AD

Tags: powershell, select, csv, active-directory, formatting

Right now I have a script that gathers user group names and the associated ManagedBy attribute  using powershell.

```
$test = 'OU=example,DC=example,DC=test'

$test | ForEach {Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy -SearchBase $_ } |
Select Name, ManagedBy |
Sort -Property Name |
Out-File C:\test.csv
```

Results come through however the managedby attribute only supplies the FQDN(Distinguished Name) when all I need is the first CN in the result.  In the case below, for example, all I need to display under ManagedBy is "testuser".  No CN= or DC= distinguished name paths.

```
Name                                     ManagedBy                           
----                                     ---------                           
TestGroup_Modify             CN=testuser,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com
```

I've tried a few things to use "-replace" with some formatting in the select but it ends up removing the first CN.

```
Select -Property Name, @{n='ManagedBy';e={$_.ManagedBy -replace '^.+?,(CN|DC.+)','$1'}}
```

results:

```
Name                                     ManagedBy                           
----                                     ---------                           
TestGroup_Modify             CN=Users,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Does anyone know a way of formatting these results or experience working with the ManagedBy attribute of a group?  I was trying to figure out a way to somehow link the ManagedBy attribute back to the users SAMAccountName but was unsuccessful/lack the powershell experience.  (I think it has something to do with the query retrieving ADGroups and not ADUsers) Thanks in advance for any help I receive on this.

The ultimate goal would be to achieve something like this:

```
Name                                     ManagedBy                           
----                                     ---------                           
TestGroup_Modify                         testuser
```

Update*

Ah okay, after changing the replace I get results like this:

```
Name                                     ManagedBy                                                
----                                     ---------                                                
TestGroup_Modify            testuser=Users,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com
```

This is helpful since it starts with the CN, but since every ManagedBy user will have

```
'=Users,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com'
```

appended, would it be possible to filter this string out from results (since all results will have it) to leave just the user CN or would that be outside the scope of powershell?  Thanks for your help.

Edit*

Here's what I ran:

```
$test = 'OU=example,DC=example,DC=test'

$test | ForEach {Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy -SearchBase $_} |
Select -Property Name, @{n='ManagedBy';e={$_.ManagedBy -replace '^CN=(.+?),(CN|OU.+)','$1'}} |
Sort -Property Name | 
Format-Table -Property Name, ManagedBy -Force -AutoSize |
Out-File C:\test.csv
```

Got these results:

```
Name                                     ManagedBy                                                
----                                     ---------                                                
TestGroup_Modify            testuser=Users,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Just looking for a way to list testuser by itself if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replace regex is not correct for what you're trying to do.

I use this one:

```
$_.ManagedBy -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:CN|OU).+','$1'
```

ManagedBy will always be a user DN, so the pattern will be CN=username, followed by either an OU or another CN if it's still in the default Users container.

Comment: I updated my script with your suggestion and it was quite helpful but I added one more question regarding this scenario in the first post if you could take a look at it

Comment: Can you post exactly what you're using.  I believe the -replace I've posted in the solution should do what you need.

Comment: I added the full script I am using to original post and results

Comment: My apologies.  Had the closing paren in the wrong place.  Updated the answer (also added ?: to make that a non-capturing group.  Won't change the result, but makes it a little more efficient).

Comment: YES! You are a legend mjolinor.  Marking this as solved.  I believe you helped me with my previous powershell question a few months ago as well.  Thank you for the time and help.  I'm still trying to understand the replace logic as it is new to me

Comment: may you help me to explain this '^CN=(.+?),(?:CN|OU).+','$1' , I wanna learn, please :)